# Extending Apache PigStorage

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I am working with data where entries can be split across two lines. I would like to extend PigStorage to support multiline entries but have questions about how that is done.

Can I override PigStorage in a standard Java UDF, or do I have to modify the PigStorage source, recompile, and push changes to my cluster?